# Fill PDF AcroForm text field with boldface text using HexaPdf

Tags: ruby, pdf

I have a seemingly simple question, but I can't find the answer. I have a pre-existing pdf form. Filling in the form manually, one of its text fields shows its value in boldface type. When using HexaPdf to fill this field, the text should also appear in boldface, but it appears in regular type.

I fill the field with

```
doc.acro_form.field_by_name('text1').field_value = @record.value
```

To get this to be shown in boldface, I have tried the following, to no avail:

```
doc.acro_form.field_by_name('text1').set_default_appearance_string(font: 'Helvetica-Bold', font_size: 0)
```

This gets the error message "The requested font 'Helvetica-Bold' in variant 'none' couldn't be found".

Then I tried:

```
doc.acro_form.field_by_name('text1').set_default_appearance_string(font: 'Helvetica', variant: :bold, font_size: 0)
```

This gets: "unknown keyword: variant".

The configured fonts for the document are:

{"Times"=>[:none, :bold, :italic, :bold_italic], "Helvetica"=>[:none, :bold, :italic, :bold_italic], "Courier"=>[:none, :bold, :italic, :bold_italic], "Symbol"=>[:none], "ZapfDingbats"=>[:none]}

So Helvetica with variant :bold should be available.

Could someone please let me know the correct syntax? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe @gettalong could give me a hint how to do this? If yes, many thanks!

Comment: @K J: I believe this is not the same case. In the link you mentioned, the issue is that the font is not available. In my case, though, I just want to use a standard font. The link to gitter unfortunately does not seem to work - would there be more information there?

Comment: Before I raise an issue I'd like to be sure it's not just an oversight on my part. If I understand correctly, set_default_appearance_string takes a font parameter which is expected to be a string. According to hexapdf/lib/hexapdf/type/font_type1.rb line 58 I expect the font name "Helvetica-Bold" to be available. Is there no way to use this in my case? Or am I missing something re correct syntax?

Comment: @K J, thanks for thinking about this with me! The problem with this syntax is that I get the error "unknown keyword: variant".

Answer (score 2):

I got this answer from @gettalong on github:

"It is indeed an issue as there is no way to do this currently with that method - I will fix it for the next release. You can use the following work-around until then:"

```
name = doc.acro_form.default_resources.add_font(doc.fonts.add('Helvetica', variant: :bold).pdf_object)
doc.acro_form.field_by_name('text1')[:DA] = "0 g /#{name} 0 Tf"
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

With the HexaPDF 0.18.0 release this is now directly possible by using the `font_options` argument for `#set_default_appearance_string`. No more work-arounds needed!